# Slide out element to right, then back in from left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Consider the following piece of HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <p id="content">
            Some content
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can make `#inner` slide **out to the right** from the screen using the following jQuery:

```
        $("#slide").animate(
            {
                'marginLeft':'100%'
            },400,
            function(){
                $(this).slideUp('fast'); 
                $(this).css("margin-right","100%");
                $(this).css("margin-left","0");
            }
        );
```

However, how can I make that same element, with **new content** (from AJAX response), slide back in **from the left?**

I was thinking about resetting the margins (from `margin-left:100%` to `margin-left:0; margin-right:100%`) while it was out of view and then use an animation to slide it in from the left:

```
        $("#slide").animate(
            {
                'marginRight':'0'
            },400,
            function(){
                $(this).slideDown('fast');
            }
        );
```

This slides it back into view, but not from the left of the screen. Any ideas? I got the `.slideUp()` from a different StackExchange question but don't know why it's needed for a horizontal slide.

Comment: Any chance you could make a fiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply reset the margin using `.css()` method:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#outer").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      'marginLeft': '100%',
      'opacity': 0
    }, 200, function() {
      //==================================
      //call synchronous ajax here or move this block 
      //to the ajax done callback function

      //some ajax change
      $(this).css({
        "background": "blue"
      }).text("came back with new content");

      $(this).css({
        'marginLeft': '-100%'
      });
      $(this).animate({
        'marginLeft': '0',
        'opacity': 1
      }, 200);
      //=================================
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <p id="content">Click Me</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent, seems as though I was almost there. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Reset the margin using `.css`, check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/gdjypc7w/2/

**JS**

```
function getSummary(id) {
    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: 'Your URL',
        data: "id=" + id,
        success: function (data) {
            // the data
            $('#summary').html(data);
        }

    });

}

$("button").click(function () {
    $("#inner").animate({
        marginLeft: $("body").width()
    }, 1000, function () {
        //$("#content").text(getSummary(id); Use your id here to retrieve new data
        $("#content").text("New content");
        $("#inner").css("margin-left", "-100%");
        $("#inner").animate({
            marginLeft: "0px"
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: At first, your fiddle made it slide back in from the right instead of the left, so I marked the other one as answer, but this works as well! Thanks.

Comment: No problemo, my pleasure :)